# select listview item display on another activity of textview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am new android developer.three java file and xml file.when In my project when all inbox msg display on listview but when i select this msg that do not display on editbox of another activity.
    below code when i select page navigate to messagebox.java to mainactivity.java but msg do not display on editbox

```
  three java files--
**Mainactivity.java**
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("Msg_Detail");
    TextView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView7);
    TextView7.setText(msg);
**MessageBox.java**
lvMsg = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMsg);
        Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

        // List required columns
        String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

        // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
        // Provider
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
        Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

        // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
                new String[] { "body", "address" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber });
        lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvMsg.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                       int position, long id) {
                      String msg=(String) lvMsg.getSelectedItem();
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                        in.putExtra("Msg_Detail", msg); 
                                        startActivity(in);

                 }
             }); 

    }
**list.java**
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.row);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMsg);
        txt2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNumber);

}
```

**activity_xml**
    
    **messagebox.xml**-all listview(Message display on listview)

```
    </ListView>
**list.xml**--all message display in textview(lblmsg and lblno)
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/lblMsg"></TextView>
    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#00f"
        android:id="@+id/lblNumber"></TextView>
```

activity_xml-contain textview and messagebox.xml-listview and list.xml-contain textview
    In select textview msg from listview display on editbox of mainactivity.java

Comment: Pls refactor your question, i cant understand anything :-/

Comment: try as `String msg =(String)(lvMsg.getItemAtPosition(position));`

Comment: when I select message(textview) unfortunately stop

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 String msg = intent.getExtras().getString("Msg_Detail");
```

Comment: debug your code and see what is the value of `msg` in `in.putExtra("Msg_Detail", msg);`?

Comment: when I debug original code in in.putExtra("Msg_Detail", msg);

Comment: this    MessageBox$1(id=8319624926654)
in    Intent(id=8319627920000)
msg null
parent ListView(id=831962821432)
view LinearLayout(id=831962667680)
position 0
id 7

Comment: message value is null